# Problem while Sending object of objects which contain file, strings, objects in the backend in react redux soring boot application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux, multipartform-data

I am making a **[contact manager application](https://github.com/debrajhyper/Personal-Contact-Manager)** similarly to phone contact applications.
**Front End - React + Redux**
**Backend - Spring Boot**

Project Link - https://github.com/debrajhyper/Personal-Contact-Manager

while Sending the **add_contact** data with Axios I am not able to receive data as expected in the backend.
I want to send data as an **object of objects** which contains **pictures, strings, and objects**. So I have to use **formdata** but with formdata I cannot send objects in the backend as it converts all to strings and in the backend, I'm using **@ModelAttribute** and **@RequestParam** to catch the request.

I am using this **values usestate** to store the data in frontend

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
        profilePic: "",
        profilePicURL: "",
        favorite: false,
        name: "",
        nickName: "",
        title: "",
        company: "",
        email: "",
        telephoneNumber: {
            code: "",
            number: ""
        },
        country: {
            code: "",
            name: "",
            no: ""
        },
        dateOfBirth: "",
        address: "",
        relationship: "",
        zodiacSign: "",
        tags: [],
        website: "",
        socialLinks: {
            facebook: "",
            twitter: "",
            linkedIn: "",
            instagram: "",
            youtube: "",
        },
        description: "",
    });
```

and on the redux side, I am generating requests with Axios

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>'
    }
}

export const addContact = (contact) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(contactRequest());

         const createFormData = (data) => {
             return Object.keys(data).reduce((formData, key) => {
                  formData.append(key, data[key]);
                  return formData;
             }, new FormData());
         };
         const data = createFormData(contact);

        axiosPrivate.post("http://localhost:1010/add-contact", data, config)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(contactSuccess(response?.data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(contactFailure(error?.response?.data?.message));
            const errorMessage = error?.response?.data?.message?.length > 100 ? 'Something went wrong' : error?.response?.data?.message;
        })
    }
};
```

------------------------------ **Modals** ------------------------------

and on the backend the modal I used to store the data **Contact.java**

```
package com.pcm.Model;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int cId;
    
    private String image;
    
    private boolean favorite;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String nickName;
    
    private String title;
    
    private String company;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ContactTelephoneNumber telephoneNumber;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ContactCountryName country;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Past(message = "The date of birth must be in the past")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    
    private String address;
    
    private String relationship;
    
    private String zodiacSign;
    
    private String[] tags;

    @Column(length = 9000)
    private String description;
    
    private String website;
    
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private ContactSocialLinks socialLinks;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

The **ContactTelephoneNumber.java** Modal

```
package com.pcm.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "telephone_number")
public class ContactTelephoneNumber {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String code;
    
    private String number;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;
    
}
```

------------------------------ **Controller** ------------------------------

```
package com.pcm.Controller;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.pcm.Model.Contact;
import com.pcm.Service.ContactService;


@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class ContactController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;
    
    @PostMapping("/add-contact")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addContact(@Valid @ModelAttribute Contact contact, @RequestParam("profilePic") MultipartFile profilePic, Principal principal ) throws Exception {
        
        String email = principal.getName();
        
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUserName(email);
        
        List<Contact> contactsByUser = this.contactRepository.findContactsByUser(user.getId());
        ListIterator<Contact> iterateContactList = contactsByUser.listIterator();
        while(iterateContactList.hasNext()) {
            if(iterateContactList.next().getEmail().equals(contact.getEmail())) {
                  throw new DuplicateKeyException("Contact already exist");
            }
        }
        
        if(profilePic.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("IMAGE FILE EMPTY");
            contact.setImage("default.png");
        } 
        else if(!profilePic.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg") && !profilePic.getContentType().equals("image/png")) {
            throw new ValidationException("Only JPEG/PNG content type are allowed");
        } 
        else {
            String imageName = contact.getCId() + "_" + profilePic.getOriginalFilename();
            
            contact.setImage(imageName);
            System.out.println("PROFILE PIC IMAGE NAME -> " + imageName);
            
            File saveFile = new ClassPathResource("static/upload/").getFile();
            Path path = Paths.get(saveFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + imageName);
            System.out.println("IMAGE LOCATION -> " + path);
            
            Files.copy(profilePic.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("IMAGE FILE SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED");
        }

        if(contact.getTelephoneNumber() != null) {
            contact.getTelephoneNumber().setContact(contact);
        }
        if(contact.getCountry() != null) {
            contact.getCountry().setContact(contact);
        }
        if(contact.getSocialLinks() != null) {
            contact.getSocialLinks().setContact(contact);
        }
        
        contact.setUser(user);
        
        User savedUserContact = this.userRepository.save(user);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Contact Added Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I want to send data as i mention in the **values usestate** as object of objects which contains file, strings and objects. And want to store the request in **Contact.java Modal**

Can anyone help me in figuring out any solution.
you can look out my project in **https://github.com/debrajhyper/Personal-Contact-Manager**

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: yes, i am not able to send data in objects format in formdata to catch the request in backend